# getElementById mysteriously returning URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a function that takes a `thumbnail` path as a value, waits for the bootstrap modal to open, and then sets the value of the `thumbnail href` within the modal to the correct path.

However, when I `console.log` the `element(el)`, I get the url of the page
i.e.

```
Element is http://localhost:8086/project/etc/etc
```

Am i missing something obvious or doing something silly?

```
  function addThumbnailPathToModal(thumbnailPath) {
      $('#my-modal').on('show.bs.modal', () => {
        const el = document.getElementById('thumbnail');
        console.log(`Element is ${el}`)
        el.setAttribute('href', thumbnailPath);
      })
    }

$('.something').on('click', '.open-modal', () => {
  const thumbnailPath = getThumbnailPathFromAttribute();
  addThumbnailPathToModal(thumbnailPath);
  $('#my-modal').modal();
});
```

Comment: Casting to string often hides important information. You should try just `console.log(el)`.

Comment: or `console.log('Element is', el)`

Answer (score 8):

When you call the template string, the `toString` function of the object is called. For historical reasons, A elements [return the href in such a case](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/toString).

The best practice to log values is to avoid logging them as strings:

```
console.log(`Element:`, el)
```

If you really need to output them to a string, `outerHTML` is probably what you want:

```
var str = `Element is ${el ? el.outerHTML : null}`;
```

Comment: Or, if your engine supports Firebug console API, `console.log("Element: %o", el)`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález You can do it in Chrome too, but there's no real gain vs simply passing several arguments

Comment: Of course not in this case, it's just a possibility when you want more complex output.